# Invertability of derivative of a bijection

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, inverse

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $f(x)$ a differentiable bijection  $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, and its inverse $f^{-1}$ also differentiable. Then $f'$ is invertible for $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to get the solution myself (so I am not asking for it), but I am confused on this example:

If $f(x)=x$, then it is differentiable, and it is its own inverse, so again, differentiable, and it is a bijection from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, but the derivative is $f'(x)=1$ is not invertible because it is not injective.

Maybe this problem only makes sense for $n\geq2$, but I don't see why because multivariable theory is built on top of single-variable.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: yes, you are missing something obvious :-). The number $1$ is invertible, and it's inverse is $1$. The associated linear map is $v \mapsto 1\cdot v$, which is injective and onto. (You are mixing up the function $f^\prime$ with the linear map induced by $f^\prime$).

Comment: but aren't we talking about the function $f(x) =1$, which is not invertible? what do you mean by "number 1 is invertible"? sorry I can't wrap my mind around it lol

Comment: I added a sentence to my comment while you were typing. Check whether that answers your question. And, no, we are _not_ talking about the function $f^\prime$, but about the linear map $v\mapsto f^\prime(x)v$.

Comment: @Thomas Do you really think someone at this stage in calculus will understand what you mean by 'linear map $v \to f'(x)v$' ?

Comment: @BCLC If they are discussing differentiable maps from $\mathbb{R}^n $ to $\mathbb{R}^n $ I actually do expect that.

Comment: That actually does make sense, thank you @Thomas

Comment: @Thomas oh I totally missed that lol thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only recently I was told that a question deserves an answer which is not just a comment...

The derivative of a differentiable map  $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ at a point $x$ is a linear map $DF(x):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ which approximates $f$ in the sense that
$$f(x+h) = f(x) + Df(x) h + o(||h||)$$

When $f$ is invertible in a neighbourhood of some $x$ and $f^{-1}$ is invertible in a neighbourhood of $f(x)$, as well, the claim you are referring to states that the *linear map*
$$DF(x):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$ is invertible. For the case $n= 1$ the derivative is just a function, often denoted by $f^\prime$. The statement in question then just means that the map $v\mapsto f^\prime(x)v$ is invertible, which is true if and only if $f^\prime (x) \neq 0$. (Think of $f^\prime(x) $ as a $1\times 1$ matrix).

The claim is *not*, that $x\mapsto f^\prime(x)$ is a function which has an inverse.